# syntax error: expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

what could possibly be the syntax error with this piece of code?

```
<%= if @post.comments != nil %>
<div id="comments">
    <%= render(:partial => "comments/comments", :object => @post_comments) %>
</div>
<%= end %>
```

it keeps on telling me this:

```
expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...nd=( if @post.comments != nil );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... 
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end ';@output_buffer.append=( end );@output_buffer.safe_append=' 
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' end ^ 
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' 
 syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

and whenever I remove the block of code above, the code works with no errors, so I am sure the errror is in this part. Any Suggestions please?

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= if @post.comments != nil %>
  ...
<%= end %>
```

should use the `<%` tag not `<%=` as they are control statements, not for output:

```
<% if @post.comments != nil %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You can find more about the use of these tags in ERB here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#templates